# publish numpy matrix to topic

Tags: ros, message, msg, topic, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I would like to publish a 10x10x10 numpy-Matrix in one publishing step.
Therefore I would like to know how I can declare the `numpy.ndarray` as a message type like

matrix.msg:

> numpy.ndarray  matrix

Is that even possible? What do I have to add to the `CMakeLists.txt` to get that running?
Is there maybe a better way?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240823/publish-numpy-matrix-to-topic/) by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried this before, the simplest way I could find was to put the matrix into row-major order and publish the data as an array. In essence, I just used the Float64MultiArray msg type and filled up that array with the matrix information and then published it. I don't know if there is a way to make a "matrix" msg type that would make this more simple, but this worked for me and I was able to get all the info passed around pretty easily.

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-08-01**:
Even though I posted the numpy tutorial I do agree that this might be the easiest solution.

**Comment by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on 2016-08-02**:
Thank you. I will do it like this for now. If I find a different approach I will add an answer here.